# Do AM radio broadcasters pick frequencies that are picked up as interference on purpose?

Tags: radio, amplitude-modulation, history

This is not meant to be a political question, rather a historical one, USA based.

Every place I have lived, if I have an amplifier with a long enough input wire, I will start picking up AM radio if I don't have a signal going through. Now I've lived in 4 places in 4 different states in the US and in every single state, 99% of the time the radio station you pick up is a Christian Broadcast owned by the Salem Media Group in the 530-570kHZ range.

Did Salem Media Group do this on purpose? Did they want people to accidently pick up their broadcasts, or is it just a coincidence that a single company seems to own all these bands?

Comment: The same goes true for my SDR devices, if I attempt to use a amplifyer...it's always the same station bleeding through

Comment: It might be that these stations are the highest-power ones in those areas, so they are the easiest to pick up with a "non-ideal" receiver. An ordinary commercial station only cares about getting their signal to the people their advertisers want to get the signal. So a station in San Francisco doesn't care much about reaching listeners in Bakersfield, because nobody's driving that far to buy a car or visit an insurance agent.

Comment: A religious broadcaster gets donations back from their audience no matter how far away they are, and also probably just wants to reach as many people as possible without consideration for ecomics. So a religious broadcaster has more interest in increasing range than a commercial one.

Comment: No.  When I was a kid, the station that came through any amp was the leading local *commercial* AM broadcaster at around 1 MHz

Comment: The lower part of the AM band travels further as a ground wave, essentially hugging the surface of the earth for a bit, than do frequencies higher up.  This translates into a larger coverage area and a wider audience.

Answer (score 3):

Coincidence.  Better amplifiers have a small RF filter on each of the signal inputs to prevent this.  This was a common problem with phono and tape preamp inputs; these have an additional 40 dB or so of gain (nominally) in the signal path.

Your equipment seems to be sensitive to the low end of the AM broadcast band.  The radio company might intentionally try to put all of their stations within a narrow range of frequencies so travelers can find them more easily when outside their normal listening area.